Problem on uniform convergence for functions
Consider two sequences of functions $(f_n)_{n=1}^\infty,(g_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ where $f_n,g_n:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$. Suppose that as $n\to \infty$:
(a) $f_n$ converges uniformly to $f$ away from a set of measure zero,
(b) $g_n$ converges to $g$ almost everywhere, and
(c) $|f_n(x)-g_n(x)|$ converges to zero almost everywhere.
Is it true that $f_n$ converges uniformly to $g$ away from a set of measure zero? My intuition tells me that the answer is yes. My reasoning is that since $f_n$ converges uniformly to its limit, call it $f$, then since $|f_n(x)-g_n(x)|$ converges to zero almost everywhere, and the sequence $(g_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ has a limit, then $f_n$ converges to $g$ almost everywhere (atleast). We can then say that this is uniform away from a set of measure zero due to (a).
Namely,
$$|f_n(x)-g(x)|=|f_n(x)+f(x)-f(x)-g(x)|\leq |f_n(x)-f(x)|+|f(x)-g(x)|.$$
and since (I think $f=g$ almost everywhere) and by (a) we can conclude $f_n$ converges uniformly to $g$ away from a set of measure zero.

More simply: by b and c, $f_n\to g$ a.e. hence by a, $g=f$ a.e., so $f_n\to g$ uniformly outside a negligeable set.
